# Django: change language from timesince

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I want to change the language of [timesince](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/timesince.py). Do I need to change directly in my django source or is there a way to modify `TIMESINCE_CHUNKS` variable in the settings file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [`./manage.py makemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#makemessages).

Then edit the `.po` files and then [`./manage.py compilemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#compilemessages).

For this to work, however, you have to go through the [internationalization chapter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/), and of course its [implementation notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#implementation-notes).